# How to create many variables with names retrieved from a database

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic

I have a database table (SQLite) Cats with the fields Name, Weight, Colour, Address, Lat, Lon and more.....
The table contains some 180 rows.
Now I want to put these cats as spots on a map with their lat/lon.
I have defined a Cat object and want to read the table and define 180 variables with the names of the cats at runtime.
Reading the data is simple enough, but I cannot find a way to define 180 variables with the cat's names in C#.

---

The database info is read into a DataTable dtCats with the columns catName, catLat, catLon (and more...)
Then I do:

```
nrOfCats = dtCats.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i< nrOfCats; i++)
{
    currentCatName = dtCats.Rows[i]["catName"].ToString();
    currentCatLat = dtCats.Rows[i]["catLat"].ToString();
    currentCatLon = dtCats.Rows[i]["catLon"].ToString();
    PointLatLng catLocation = new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(currentCatLat), Convert.ToDouble(currentCatLon));
    GmapMarker <the value of currentCatName> = new GMarkerGoogle(catLocation, GMarkerGoogleType.green_pushpin);   // this <the value of currentCatName> is the problem
    mapOverlayCatMarkers.Markers.Add(<the value of currentCatName>, catLocation);
}
```

etc....
(Of course this "" is not the variable name, It should be the value of the currentCatName variable)

Comment: Why are you trying to create 180 variables instead os storing them in a collection?

Comment: This approach is fundamentally fighting the language you're working in.

Comment: Side note: please don't add thank you notes, signature and "searched alot" to you posts. If you want to show your research effort - put code you've tried or include links to questions/articles you've found with one line description why it did not work for your case.

Answer (score 4):

Theres a good reason for that, you *shouldn't be declaring that many variables*. Instead, you should have a `Cat` class that holds all those fields, and then have a `List<Cat>` to hold all the instances made from your database.

Something like:

```
List<Cat> data = new List<Cat>();

for (int i = 0; i < TableRows.Count; i++) //Made up for loop, 
                                          //use whatever makes sense for your code
{
    Cat record = new Cat();

    //Populate data

    data.Add(record);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if the map library (Gmap.net) requires 180 explicit variable names for map markers?
Jennifer

Comment: @JenniferBanks Can you show what the code looks like for adding a marker?

Comment: @JenniferBanks If your library is using actual variable names for its markers (indicating that its using reflection), you should probably not use that library. Regardless, some code would be nice.

Comment: To explain it a little more:
The values catName, catLat and catLon are stored in a database table.
In the following code, I would like to replace the text: catName with some value from my database:

PointLatLng catLocation = new PointLatLng(catLat, catLon);
GMapMarker  catName = new GMarkerGoogle(catLocation, GMarkerGoogleType.green_pushpin);
catName.ToolTipText =  catName;
mapOverlaylMarkers.Markers.Add( catName);

Comment: @JenniferBanks Why can't `catName` be a "nameless" instance of `Cat` in a collection? What is the purpose in having all of them as individual variables? If you need 180 variables, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm sure I do it wrong, so could you please suggest a way to create several GMapMarkers with unique names at runtime?

Comment: @JenniferBanks I would be happy to, but I'm not familiar with that library. Could you post some sample code of how you are currently doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    mapOverlayCatMarkers.Markers.Add(new GMarkerGoogle(catLocation, GMarkerGoogleType.green_pushpin), catLocation);
```

you do not need 180 variables for the Add call, just 180 objects. if you do not need these onjects later, you can just create them anonymously like this, or assign them all to the sam variable in your loop.
if you do need to access them later, a List as others have mentioned is a possibility.